# How to allow IIS express to access any file extensio

Tags: iis, mime

I have multiple images but i have changed the extension for my own purpose. So I have multiple extension. When I try to display my image I got an error that my extension is not mapped to a mime type.
So how can I display my image without changing the extension because I have a lot.
With Apache wamp server I tested all images and it can be displayed.

Then with IIS express included within visual studio 2017, is there a way to do the mapping. I also did the mapping individually but this cannot be good solution for me because I have many images file.

Answer (score 11):

You can change the config file that IIS express use it:

1. Right click on IIS Express icon on traybar then click on "**Show All Application**"

[image: open config file]

2. Select  your application name and click on config address in bottom of application list.

[image: open config file]

3. Opened file contains xml elements. you must find "**staticConten**" element then add your intended mapping.

[image]

Comment: This does not work.  The config file is locked so I cannot edit it.  If I stop the server, the config file is deleted, so I cannot edit it.

Comment: @JohnHenckel the file isn't deleted in my machine. I followed the steps above, but once I had the file open and before editing it I stopped the execution of the app, then I edited the file and then I re-ran the app and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you run iisexpress.exe from the command line, the config file it uses will be in `AppServer/applicationhost.config`.  Add the mime types you need to that file in the section <staticContent> and restart iisexpress.

Comment: You just ended a day's worth of suffering for me, thank you so much for this answer. I've added mime types everywhere but in this file, and nothing worked.